# How to display line count where regex match was found

Tags: python, regex, count

I've seen several examples of how to display a line count, and have tried to implement those into my code, but was unsuccessful. I am a Python newbie, so I guess I have more to learn. Can someone show me how I would display the line count of the match found in a file, thanks?

```
elif searchType =='3':
      print "Directory to be searched: c:\SQA_log "
      print " "
      directory = os.path.join("c:\\","SQA_log")

      regex = re.compile(r'(?:3\d){6}')
      for root,dirname, files in os.walk(directory):
         for file in files:
           if file.endswith(".log") or file.endswith(".txt"):
              f=open(os.path.join(root,file))
              for line in f.readlines():
                  searchedstr = regex.findall(line)
                  for word in searchedstr:
                     print "String found: " + word
                     print "File: " + os.path.join(root,file)
                     break
                     f.close()
```

Comment: Line count? you mean the line number where the word is found? Or the number of lines with the matching word?

Comment: the last `f.close()` is at a funny location :)

Comment: @Spencer Rathbun - the line number where the word is found!

Comment: @Aviral Dasgupta - oops copying, pasting, and trying to dress your code for the public can be dangerous ... :)!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Well, I'm assuming you want to output the *line number* as well. For that, you'd do:

```
  regex = re.compile(r'(?:3\d){6}')
  for root,dirname, files in os.walk(directory):
     for file in files:
       if file.endswith(".log") or file.endswith(".txt"):
          f=open(os.path.join(root,file))
          for i, line in enumerate(f.readlines()):
              searchedstr = regex.findall(line)
              for word in searchedstr:
                 print "String found: " + word
                 print "Line: "+str(i)
                 print "File: " + os.path.join(root,file)
                 break
          f.close()
```

Comment: I got the error: "Cannot concatenate string and int object." ("Line: " + i). So, I did ln = str(i) => "Line: " + ln

Comment: @user706808 oops... JavaScript overdose. Fixed it now. Should be `+str(i)`

Answer (score 2):

See http://docs.python.org/library/functions.html#enumerate. Change your loop with iterates over line like this:

```
for i,line in enumerate(f.readlines()):
```

i will hold the line number